# How can I assert that a certain HTTP request is called after I click a button?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, casperjs

I have a simple page that when you click the 'Get Info' button it will call the API getinfo/ and return data to client to render on page. Normally, I could automate the whole flow using selenium, click the button and then parsing the UI elements to compare with result data. However, I see that automation test is not efficiency because:
- What I really want to check is when I click button, does it call the API for me?
- I already have a test case to check that if I call the API getinfo/1 it will return correct data for me.

So, I don't know if selenium, casperjs or jmeter has any methods that can satisfy my need ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, could you elaborate with a specific code you tried and errors you got? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have no code yet. My example is, if I click button "Get Info", is there anyway to check that the system will make a HTTP request getinfo/1 to server or nor?

Comment: you can use this http://bmp.lightbody.net/

Comment: @NguyenDuongHai Yes, you can do that in plain CasperJS, but you would probably be able to do this with Selenium+PhantomJS. You should reduce the scope of your question and concentrate on one technology.

Comment: In addition to above suggestions: You can also use browser mob proxy and capture the network requests made by your application and store it in a file and then parse the log to check if any request was to desired api -- if you just want to check the call was made or not .